# Export console output to excel sheet in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I have a python code that contains some print statements and the output looks like a hierarchy shown. Is there a way to export what is printed in jupyter book as it is to an excel worksheet?

I tried a python list
first I put `myList = []` then inside the iteration loops and before each print statement, I appended the output to the `myList` like that `myList.append('Any thing')`

And in a jupyter notebook cell I used the following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame() 
df["My Output"] = myList
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Result.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

But the output was only one column .. There are spaces and tabs in the output

It looks like that

```
* ag
    + bb
        - yy
        - nn
        - oo
        - ss
    + ccc
        - tt
    + ddd
* ah
    + eee
        - ppp
        - olp
        - ws
        - ort
    + fff
        - kpr
    + ggg
```

As for the output I expect is to get three columns (a column for each symbol) so the asterisk * would be in a column and the plus is in another column and the minus is in another column
[image]

I have made this code for illustration purposes so as to know how the `myList` looks like

```
myList = []

myList.append('*' + 'ag')
print('*' + 'ag')

myList.append('\t+' + 'bb')
print('\t+' + 'bb')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'yy')
print('\t\t-' + 'yy')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'nn')
print('\t\t-' + 'nn')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'oo')
print('\t\t-' + 'oo')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'ss')
print('\t\t-' + 'ss')

myList.append('\t+' + 'ccc')
print('\t+' + 'ccc')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'tt')
print('\t\t-' + 'tt')

myList.append('\t+' + 'ddd')
print('\t+' + 'ddd')

myList.append('*' + 'ah')
print('*' + 'ah')

myList.append('\t+' + 'eee')
print('\t+' + 'eee')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'pp')
print('\t\t-' + 'pp')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'olp')
print('\t\t-' + 'olp')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'ws')
print('\t\t-' + 'ws')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'ort')
print('\t\t-' + 'ort')

myList.append('\t+' + 'fff')
print('\t+' + 'fff')

myList.append('\t\t-' + 'kpr')
print('\t\t-' + 'kpr')

myList.append('\t+' + 'ggg')
print('\t+' + 'ggg')
```

Comment: @QHarr Any help in this topic?

Comment: @MaxU Any help in this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import re

newlist = []

for string in mylist:
    row = re.findall(r'\t', string)    #get a list of all the '\t' characters
    value = re.search(r'\S+', string).group()   #extract the value eg. '+bb'
    row.append(value)    #append the value on to the end of the row.
    for x in range(3-len(row):
        row.append('\t')    #right pad the list with '\t' so all rows have length 3
    newlist.append(row)    #append the new row (eg. ['\t', '+bb', '\t'] to the list)

df = pd.DataFrame(newlist)    #create a dataframe.
df = df.replace('\t', '')    #replace '\t' characters with empty strings
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The dataframe I got are the symbols only without the data next to those symbols.

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in my answer. Use '\S+' instead of '\S' in the second regex to capture 1 or more non-whitespace characters (eg. '+bb') instead of just 1 (eg. '+').

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for the great help. One last point how can I remove the symbols and the extra spaces in the output.

Comment: I would suggest you read up on regexes and how to use the built in re module. Regexes are an invaluable coding skill and it's well worth taking the time to get comfortable with them. eg. the regex pattern '\w+' will match one or more 'word characters' (letters, numbers and underscores); regex pattern "\s*" will match zero or more 'whitespace characters' (spaces, tabs etc.).